# How to manage versions of a software in Git at the enterprise situation?

Tags: git, version-control, development-environment, branching-and-merging, git-rebase

I want to develop a new project that has two versions (Basic version and Pro version).
Basic version and Pro version have some customization. So i thought how i should manage branches properly to meet my requirements.
This is the result of my thought:

[image: First state]

[image]

The second image shows an update of some bug fixes from `Version1.0` branch into `Release1.0` branch and `Master` branch and `Version2.0` branch.
What's your opinion?
How can i perform `Shift forward...` operation (in the second image)?
(I must use Git)

Comment: Have you considered using [Feature Toggles](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html) rather than branching your code?

Comment: Thank you but i looking for branching solution. It is more clear and simple.

Comment: What is it about feature toggles that you fund unclear or complicated? In my experience branch-based "solutions" lead to huge maintenance overheads.

Comment: You must strictly manage source code. Imagine that there is many developer. It seems to be a complicated way. Also source will have many many if-then clause. If you have some features that works different in new version you need to keep old one available and usable(you need to be careful) and make new one usable too. Git approach make project more clear and it is suitable for team work.

Comment: Short-lived branches in Git are definitely good for productivity. However, working on large codebases with many developers and having long-lived branches means that many developer hours can be wasted integrating and testing changes. Having all features on one branch reduces this overhead and makes it obvious where features lie.

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier to start with a standard workflow for Git: **[git-flow](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/)**, defined in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow).
See this [Getting Started article](http://yakiloo.com/getting-started-git-flow/):

[image: workflow git-flow]

That would manage both the releases *and* the features.

Comment: Thank you. This flow show multiple merge for any hotfix. This is not a good idea because of complexity. Where can i perform release customization? (e.g. Basic version and Pro version. this customization is repeated on version1.2 for example) There is not possible to isolate developing version 1.0 from version 2.0 (Please note that some bug fixes are for some features that is deprecated in version2.0 and i want to long support version1.0). Also `develop` branch is very unstable because feature developing (results new bugs).